# Ramda find two different nested key values

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, npm, ramda.js

I new in this Ramda, Possible to get the two different key values in same level of object?.

I added same code in below:

Here, the list object have users and employee keywords, I try to achieve to get both users and employee details.

```
const R = require('ramda');

var list = [
  {"doc":{"Title":"test1","Relations":{"users":[{"name": "user1"}]}}},
  {"doc":{"Title":"test2","Relations":{"employee":[{"name": "user2"}]}}}
];

var getDetails=  R.map(
  R.pipe(
    R.prop('doc'),
    R.pipe(R.path(['Relations', 'users']))
  )
)

getDetails(list);
```

In my code I used users key only. possible to get both keys(users and employee).

Current Output:

```
[[{"name": "user1"}], undefined]
```

Expecting Output:

```
[[{"name": "user1"}], [{"name": "user2"}]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not too far away from a solution with what you already have.

Some other functions that can help here are:

- [`R.pick`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick) - which will transform an object to only include the keys you provide (e.g. `users`, `employee`).
- [`R.values`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#values) - Ramda's function equivalent to `Object.prototype.values`.
- [`R.chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) - this allows you to map over your list and then flatten the resulting nested list.

```js
const list = [
  {"doc":{"Title":"test1","Relations":{"users":[{"name": "user1"}]}}},
  {"doc":{"Title":"test2","Relations":{"employee":[{"name": "user2"}]}}}
]

const getDetails = R.chain(R.pipe(
  R.path(['doc', 'Relations']),
  R.pick(['users', 'employee']),
  R.values
))

const result = getDetails(list)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi, sorry to bother you. I added new question but different approach. could you please help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170414/node-ramda-find-the-object-based-on-value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ifElse` and `isNil` functions:

```
var getDetails=  R.map(
  R.pipe(
    R.prop("doc"),
    R.pipe(
      R.ifElse(
        R.pipe(R.path(["Relations", "users"]), R.isNil),
        R.path(["Relations", "employee"]),
        R.path(["Relations", "users"])
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: I added new question but different approach. could you please help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170414/node-ramda-find-the-object-based-on-value