# Node Ramda + find the object based on value

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, npm, ramda.js

Possible to get object based on the value?

In below sample json, the key name have **type**, so based on type value need to fetch the results.

For example if type='user' then fetch the result only for users object not for employee object.

Here I am struggling have both keys(users and employee), Could you please suggest to how to approach

```js
var list =[
  {"doc":{"type":"user","Title":"test1","Relations":{"users":[{"name": "user1"},{"name": "user2"},{"name": "user3"}],"employee":[{"emp": "user2"}]}}},
  {"doc":{"type":"employee","Title":"test2","Relations":{"users":[{"name": "user1"}],"employee":[{"name": "emp1"},{"name": "emp2"},{"name": "emp3"}]}}}
];

const getDetails = R.chain(R.pipe(
  R.path(['doc', 'Relations']),
  R.pick(['users', 'employee']),
  R.values
))

const result = getDetails(list)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Current Output:

```
[[{"name": "user1"}, {"name": "user2"}, {"name": "user3"}], [{"emp": "user2"}], [{"name": "user1"}], [{"name": "emp1"}, {"name": "emp2"}, {"name": "emp3"}]]
```

Expecting output:

```
[[{"name": "user1"}, {"name": "user2"}, {"name": "user3"}], [{"name": "emp1"}, {"name": "emp2"}, {"name": "emp3"}]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`R.cond`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) to branch logic based on a set of predicates, like whether `type` is `user` or `employee` in your example.

With this approach you will need to switch your `R.chain` to `R.map` to match your expected list, unless you want the extra flattening of the arrays.

```js
const list = [
  {"doc":{"type":"user","Title":"test1","Relations":{"users":[{"name": "user1"},{"name": "user2"},{"name": "user3"}],"employee":[{"emp": "user2"}]}}},
  {"doc":{"type":"employee","Title":"test2","Relations":{"users":[{"name": "user1"}],"employee":[{"name": "emp1"},{"name": "emp2"},{"name": "emp3"}]}}}
]

const getDetails = R.map(R.pipe(
  R.prop('doc'),
  R.cond([
    [R.propEq('type', 'user'), R.path(['Relations', 'users'])],
    [R.propEq('type', 'employee'), R.path(['Relations', 'employee'])]
  ])
))

const expected = [[{"name": "user1"}, {"name": "user2"}, {"name": "user3"}], [{"name": "emp1"}, {"name": "emp2"}, {"name": "emp3"}]]

console.log(R.equals(expected, getDetails(list)))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```